# SAM CLI for running Lambda functions locally fails when building docker image with x86_64 problem

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Host Machine: Mac M1
SAM version: 1.70.0
CDK version: 2.60.0 (build 2d40d77)

In our `api_stack.py` file we have a simple setup of

- API Gateway REST endpoints
- Lambda functions triggered by API Gateway

The entire codebase was initially setup with `cdk init`
When we run `cdk synth`, we get a files generated in the folder `cdk.out` including the `api.template.json` which is the CloudFormation template file.

Following commands all work:
cdk synth
cdk deploy

However when we run `sam local invoke` or `sam local start-api`, I get an error that looks like below.

```
% sam local invoke GetUserTemporary -t cdk.out/api.template.json -e events/get_user/prod-user.json

Invoking get_user_temporary.handler.handle (python3.9)
DependenciesLayerDF300E31 is a local Layer in the template
Local image was not found.
Building image.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Failed to build Docker Image
NoneType: None
Error: Error building docker image: The command '/bin/sh -c mv /var/rapid/aws-lambda-rie-x86_64 /var/rapid/aws-lambda-rie && chmod +x /var/rapid/aws-lambda-rie' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This used to work just about 1 week ago and now it is showing this error all of sudden. Exact same codebase is git cloned in my co-workers' machines.

- Windows
- Mac M1
  And this all works for them. I try to do this in my M1 laptop and it fails now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to specifically specify what architecture you are using when defining your lambda functions in your CDK Python source code. You can achieve this by adding the `architecture=` argument like below.

```
fn = _lambda.Function(
    self,
    func_name,
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('api/lambda_fns'),
    handler=f'{func_path}.handle',
    layers=[self.layer],
    role=role,
    architecture=_lambda.Architecture.X86_64,
)
```